# How do you auto generate SDF in Code First approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I've create a POCO and a context and have added EF to my project from NuGet (v4.3.1). The app.config looks a little new to me as compared to what I've been used to. It has this section in there:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <!--<parameter value="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Test.sdf; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />-->
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

I've commented out the 'parameter' and add a connection string snippet instead like this under the  tag at the top:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CodeFirstExampleContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Test.sdf;Initial Catalog=CodeFirstExample;integrated security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Previously with a connection string like that the SQL CE database would get auto-generated. however it isn't doing that now. Instead I get the following exception:

"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."

The Inner exception is:

"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."

Here are my POCO and Context types:

```
class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}


class Context:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection string to:

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Test.sdf"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

And change the default connection factory:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. I had actually tried that previously. I noticed that that was the format generated if I tried adding a new 'database file' to the project and selecting SQL Server CE as the source.

Comment: The name must match the full name of your DbContext, or use name=CodeFirstExampleContext in the DbContext constructor - see http://petebarber.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-nunit-and-entity-framework.html